# Cycles Engine: Normal Map Black Outline

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

Is anybody aware of an issue where normal maps add a black outline into cycles rendering?

For comparison see the image:

[image: Cycles Rendering with and without normal map]

Is there a solution to fix this behaviour?

Here is the Material setup (normal-map node is disconnected right now)

[image: Glossy BSDF Material Setup]

Comment: What are the settings of the material setup and normal map?

Comment: I´ve added a screenshot

Comment: Try changing color space of the normal map from Color to Non-Color Data, that's how normal maps are set up (it could be also for roughness map but not necessarily).